# How to install hashlib in Django - it's missing in my server but working in localhost

Tags: django

How do I install hashlib in django?

It's missing in my server but working in localhost.

Answer (score 3):

`hashlib` is bundled with Python since version 2.5. Your server must be using 2.4 or older. The most straightforward solution is to update Python on your server. If this is not an option for you, however, `hashlib` is [available as a package on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib).